# Helper Kanji: What is 状 doing here

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Given the sentence:

> 今日は大学の講義で日本状の経営について学んだ。

I usually interpretate 状 as 'state, condition', but that doesn't seem to fit here (japanese state of business management?).  Looking online, lead to 状 as 'styled' and 'japanese styled business management' does make way more sense.

How often does 状 mean 'styled'?   Are there other examples?

Why doesn't 日本式 work here instead?

Comment: I'd say it's probably an OCR error for 流... 日本状 makes no sense to me.

Comment: Could you mention the source of this sentence? It might help.

Comment: Looks like this is from [a JLPT N2 quiz](https://kakomon-quiz.com/jlpt/en/n2/kmondai_k.php?Y=3&q=13) (and probably sourced from the real JLPT N2 2016-2 test, Q.13), though it seems the expected answer is indeed "日本式".

Answer (score 3):

なんかこれ変。

The statement "今日は大学の講義で日本状の経営について学んだ。" just doesn't sound right to me and I'm a native. I can see what it wants to say, but it just isn't right. Is this on some sort of textbook? Where is this from? At least it certainly isn't something a Japanese person would write. You are right to suggest 式.

Alternatively, 流 (ryu) would work too.

今日は大学の講義で日本式の経営について学んだ。
今日は大学の講義で日本流の経営について学んだ。